# java having trouble with multiple classes

Tags: java

so I'm trying to use a switch so that when i click on a range of 1 to 4, each one is directed to a class and performs its function. The choice "1" should asks for the user to input the id, name, other name and marks, then calculate it's average. The second class should then display all the information and I'm not sure how to do it.

Here is my main code:

```
public class lab3q1 {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        Entries entriesobject = new Entries(); //object declaration
        display displayobject = new display(); //object declaration
        displayall displayallobject = new displayall(); //object declaration
        sortdata sortdataobject = new sortdata();

        System.out.println("1. Add new entries: ");
        System.out.println("2. Display an entry: ");
        System.out.println("3. Display all entries: ");
        System.out.println("4. Sort Data: ");
        System.out.println("5. Exit: ");
        int s = sc.nextInt();

        switch(s){

                case 1:{
                    if(s==1)
                    try{
                        entriesobject.method0();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println("You can't do that");

                    }
                }
                case 2:{
                    if(s==2){
                        try{
                        displayobject.method();
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("You can't do that");
                        }
                    }

                }

                case 3:{
                    if(s==3){
                        try{
                        displayallobject.method2();
                    }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            System.out.println("You can't do that");
                        }   
                    }
                }
                case 4:{
                    if(s==4){
                        try{
                            sortdataobject.method3();
                        }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                System.out.println("You can't do that");
                    }   
                    }
                }
                case 5:{
                    if(s==5){break;}
                }               
   }
  }
}
```

Here is the first class:

```
public class Entries {    
    public void method0(){          
        int total=0,total2;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the student id: ");
        int id = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the student name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the student other names: ");
        String othername = sc.nextLine();

        for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){

        System.out.println("Enter the student marks" +(i));
        int mark = sc.nextInt();
        total += mark;
        total2 =total/4;
        System.out.println("The average marks is: "+total2); 
        }           
    }       
}
```

And here is my second class:

```
public class display {
  public void method() {            
        int n;          
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.println("Here is the student id: ");         
    }    
}
```

As you can see i can't seem to link them.

Comment: Sorry i didn't mean click, i meant type.

Comment: Sorry pal, horrible horrible code. You want us to spend our time to help you, so you please spend the 5 minutes it takes to properly format/indent all of your source code to make it human readable. Then: you **only** use try catch if a method can throw a checked exception. You don't put down try/catch blindly; and more importantly: you **print** the exception you caught because that tells you **what went wrong**. Just catching an error, and just printing "some error" doesn't help at all!

Comment: To add to @GhostCat comment, name your methods to reflect what they are doing. If you can't find a good name, you'll have to rethink what it should actually do.

Comment: forgive me for all those errors, yes i know that the try and catch was useless, but i was just seeing how it works. I'm kind of a beginner and your comment helps a lot.

Comment: And as said; you want us to help you. And by having **any** code in your question that isn't important for your question... you make that harder. btw: you also make things harder for **yourself**. Each and any line in your code ... is there for a reason. If that reason is no longer valid: throw that line away. Immediately. Do not carry *waste* around!

Comment: Why do you use _switch-case_ and _if_ together? Use _break_ instead of the _if_-s in the cases, so the next case won't run.

Comment: @GhostCat ok sure! got it. and thx again for your time with me.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: when different classes want to know about data in **other** classes (aka fields of other objects), you need ways to access that, like:

```
public class Student {
  private int id;
  ... methods to put a value into id

  public int getId() { return id; }
```

and then some other class that **has** one more Student objects can do.

Beyond that: you are getting your "separation of concerns" wrong. You should have **one** class that uses a scanner to "collect" data from the user. This class creates various **other** objects; and puts the data from the user into those objects.

All your **other** classes do not have / need a scanner object. They **get** their data, for example as parameters to their constructor.

```
System.out.println("The id is: " + someStudentObject.getId());
```

Comment: I put in some more updates. But the real message here: please study some more tutorials/books first. Your code is *far* from doing anything remotely useful. And this is not programming school where we hold your hand and fix all the zillions of smaller and bigger problems in your code.

Comment: I guess when you wrote "classes" on your first paragraph you meant "instances"...cause you're referring to both instance properties and methods.